# Prepopulate edit form fields with database data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

First of all i want to say that I'm new to Django, but I'm enjoying it alot. Atm I am trying to make a kinda simple bank account management website. I've done the registration, views, user restrictions (logged, anonymous user), user customization(password change, edit profile informations). And I stopped on the last one. The problem is that whenever I'm on the edit-profile url, the edit profile form (EditProfileForm) doesn't display the currently field values in the input boxes [Edit Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3KH2.png)

As you see, the fields are empty although there's values in database (I can check with the admin-page or my custom ProfileView)

## models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

username = models.CharField(_('username'),
    max_length=20,
    unique=True,
    help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
    validators=[username_validator],
    error_messages={
        'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
    },)
password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128, default='')
first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150)
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'))
card_nr = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='')
location = models.CharField(choices=CHOISE_LOCATIONS, max_length=20, default='')
phone_number = models.CharField(_('phone number'), max_length=10, default='')
bank_account = models.CharField(_('bank account'), max_length=20, default='')


EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']


def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(username=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)

## forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
card_nr = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'pattern': r'^[0-9]+$'}), max_length=16)
location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOISE_LOCATIONS)
phone_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'pattern': r'^[0-9]+$'}), max_length=10)

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'card_nr',
        'location',
        'phone_number',
    ]
```

## views.py

```
def edit_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        location = form.cleaned_data['location']
        card_nr = form.cleaned_data['card_nr']

        #BANK ACCOUNT CREATION
        bank_id = 'RO' + (str(ord(first_name[0])) + str(ord(first_name[-1])))[-2:] + \
                        'BANK' + (str(ord(first_name[0])) + str(ord(first_name[-1])))[:3] + \
                        (str(ord(last_name[0])) + str(ord(last_name[-1])))[:3] + (card_nr[:3]) + (card_nr[-3:])
        #-------------------------

        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(username=user)
        user_profile.first_name = first_name
        user_profile.last_name = last_name
        user_profile.email = email
        user_profile.phone_number = phone_number
        user_profile.location = location
        user_profile.card_nr = card_nr
        user_profile.bank_account = bank_id
        user_profile.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
else:
    form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)

    args = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

Let me know if i'm missing something. I've tried by changing the view form, by adding the id and instances like:

```
def edit_profile(request, id):
instance = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, id=id)
form = EditProfileForm(instance=instance)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
```

EDIT:
edit_profile.html

```html
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <br>
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'accounts:edit_profile' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: try removing everything except the Meta class and its contents from your form

Comment: When you are using ModelForm you can use it's [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method instead of getting and setting the UserProfile by yourself.
Can you show us the edit_profile.html?

Comment: In your first version, you're setting the `instance` to `request.user` which is wrong, since the form requires a `UserProfile` instance. Your second version should work. But it depends a bit on your template, how does `edit_profile.html` look like?

Comment: (unrelated to the issue) Note: your `UserProfile` stores information that's already stored by the `User` object, like `username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`. You should create a `OneToOneField` on your `UserProfile` model to the `User` and not duplicate fields.

Comment: You can add it yourself in your template. I know, it's not an efficiency way, but a quite intuitive way.